# How to Transpose dataframe with custom output?

Tags: python, dataset, data-science-model, dataframe

I have a data like this:

[image]

I want to transpose it like this in python:

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no explanation on what the user already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.pivot_table(values='Confirmed',index['state','State_name'],columns='date',aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: You just missed a '=' after index. It worked. :)

Comment: cool, thanks for the update